# Enforce ordering without enforcing dependency

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have some "phony" targets that I occasionally want to run in a specific order, but are not strictly dependent on each other. For example:

```
.PHONY: image-build
image-build: Dockerfile
    docker build --tag foobar --file $< .

.PHONY: image-tag
image-tag: image-build
    docker tag foobar foobar:latest

.PHONY: image-push
image-push:
    docker push foobar:latest
```

I don't *always* want to run `image-tag` before `image-push`. However, if I *do* happen to run them together, as in `make image-tag image-push`, I want to ensure that `image-tag` runs *before* `image-push`.

That is, whenever `image-tag` and `image-push` both appear in the dependency graph, I want `image-tag` to be executed first, but when `image-push` is in the dependency graph and `image-tag` is not, I do *not* want `image-tag` to be added to the dependency graph.

Is it possible to enforce this rule in GNU Make?

For now, I have created a workaround command:

```
.PHONY: image-deploy
image-deploy: image-tag
    $(MAKE) image-push
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
image-push: $(filter image-tag,$(MAKECMDGOALS))
         docker push foobar:latest
```

The `filter` will expand to nothing if `image-tag` is not specified as a goal target (on the command line), else it will expand to `image-tag`.